# Android Studio doesn't see Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to create a new project, and Android Studio does not see any of the Android sdk.

Version info:

Android Studio v0.8.2

Steps to reproduce:

1. New Project -> Next -> Next -> Blank Activity -> Finish
2. Go to MyActivity.java and notice that all Android classes are not recognized.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio go to File > Project Structure > SDK Location (left tab) and select your default SDK path.

**Edit

Each project has its own SDK location property also.  Try clicking on "local.properties" in project files and changing "sdk.dir" to the correct path.

Comment: Try clicking on the "Gradle" tab on the right side of Andriod Studio and then click on the refresh icon in the top left of the popup.

Comment: Refresh doesn't help. Trying a re-install now

Comment: That's set as well. I've checked everything. I don't get it.

Comment: Does Android Studio display any errors in the "Messages" panel?

Comment: Nope, it builds fine. But the IDE shows all the Android classes as Red and won't auto complete anything related to Android.

Comment: Strange.  You may want to try and reset Android Studio to default settings and not import your IntelliJ settings to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: External Libraries has '< Maven Android API 19 Platform >` where is it getting that from?

Comment: Mine says: '< Android API Platform 19 >' and the path to the sdk after it.  Do you have v19 downloaded?

Comment: I have it downloaded in the sdk dir in the usual spot. That's also the path that's listed after < Maven Android API 19 Platform >. Not sure how to reset it, it's not in module setting or project structure.

Comment: I re-imported the project, then a "setup sdk" popup showed up. I set it to < Android API Platform 19 > and now it's happy. Weird.